# Cannot read property 'list' of null - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Im creating a Notification component using Vuex to store data API and called it in components but I have some issues

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="notification_check">
     <div class="header">
        <span>Notifications </span>
        <span>(1)</span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <ul v-for="notification in $store.state.notification.notifications.list" :key="notification.id">
    {{notification.id}}
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      config: {
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token
        }
      },
      notifications: this.$store.state.notification.notifications.list
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.getNotification()
  },
  methods: {
    getNotification: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('getNotification', this.config)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is Action Commit:

```
getNotification ({commit}, config) {
    api.get(`/notifications/`, config)
    .then(response => {
      commit('GET_NOTIFICATION', response.data)
    })
  },
```

This is my data API which stored in Vuex Store. Please take a look:
[image]

**Error occurs:**
`Cannot read property 'list' of null`

Comment: How are you initialising the store? That’s the vital part of information that is currently missing...

Comment: You might also want to look at using `getters` for Vuex. Saves all that messing around with chaining to find the correct state property.

Comment: replace $store.state.notification.notifications.list with notifications